# Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the same variance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm trying to prove an equality and am just looking for different ways to approach it. I'm curious if there is any useful knowledge that comes from knowing that two random variables have the same variance.

I'm currently studying the topic of covariance and correlations. So, are there any relationships or properties that we can assume about $X$ and $Y$ knowing that they have the same variance?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that $X$ and $Y$ have finite second moments, and so $\mathbb E[|XY|]<\infty$ by Hölder's inequality. Therefore the covariance (and hence the correlation) of $X$ and $Y$ exists. Recall that
$$\operatorname{Var}(X+Y) = \operatorname{Var}(X) + \operatorname{Var}(Y) +2\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y), $$
and so $$\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = \frac12\operatorname{Var}(X+Y) - \operatorname{Var}(X). $$
From this it follows that 
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Corr}(X,Y) &= \frac{\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X)\operatorname{Var}(Y)}}\\
&= \frac{\frac12\operatorname{Var}(X+Y) - \operatorname{Var}(X)}{\operatorname{Var}(X)}\\
&= \frac{\operatorname{Var}(X+Y)}{2\operatorname{Var}(X)}-1.
\end{align}